# sails and ember with sockets

Tags: ember.js, socket.io, sails.js

well i'm trying to do a realtime app with ember sails and socket.io
my app work ok in CHROME but in firefox it doesn't work, in console it logs, "Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails" and it never connect. but in chrome it do ok.

I include sails.io.js in my vendor folder and in my ember-cli.build.js.

any ideas?

thanks